# What constitutes a “Rule 69 agreement” after a judge has issued a final ruling and required mediation?

Tags: family-law, arizona

The context is in Arizona and I'm wondering how can a party prove an agreement existed.

Answer (score 3):

### It has to be in writing

To prove it exists you can point to it and say “that’s it”.

Further, to be valid it must be stated on the record in court or before a Judge Pro Tem, before a court reporter, or any other mediator or settlement conference officer appointed by the court to conduct a settlement conference. They’ll have a copy of it.